# Linux scheduler history

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I have a process running on Linux which creates a lot of pThreads (each of them have its own purpose). Let's say by some reason one of threads crashes. Sometimes, crash might be caused by some other thread and it would be good to know what threads were running before the crashed one.

**So the question is:**
Is there a way to ask Linux scheduler what last threads were scheduled?

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why does it matter to you? I believe you cannot make a reasonable difference between 2 running threads (out of 10 runnable threads) on a fast machine with a small scheduling period (some `HZ` configured in the kernel, here preemptive) and 5 running threads (out of 10 runnable threads) on a slower machine. The scheduler is permitted to run a task at will and task scheduling can happen at any *machine* instruction! The kernel tries hard to give you the illusion that all runnable threads are slowing running simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are aware of the Linux "top" command which can show you all the threads open by your process:

> top -H -p "pid of your process"

I may help to identify that how many threads are running which is stopped or crashed.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to make changes in kernel code to gather the scheduling data at each context switch and keep writing in some place in memory, it is somewhat similar to Flight recorder functionality available in PNE kernel.

Comment: I'm afraid that could significantly slow task scheduler.

Comment: there is a little overhead. All PNE kernels use this feature

Comment: well but not everyone is having PNE kernel as that is more of proprietary kernel not a open source kernel. You can quote example from similar stuff available in open source called kdump.

Comment: That is no more a proprietary kernel. NVRAM is used for this pupose and a small change can be made to accomodate this